# What other sites are using the Stack Overflow engine?

Tags: discussion, so-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Stack Exchange sites are up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20291/what-stack-exchange-sites-are-up)

I just saw [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). What other sites are based on StackOverflow?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: Dupe on meta several times; for answer, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: StackOverflow, SuperUser, ServerFault, Meta, and all the ones listed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites Also, here is a list of known clones: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: Interesting that MSO didn't suggest any of those dupes when I typed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites), but beware, they're all going away soon, as per this [link](http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0).

Also, see the bottom of the page for a few more computer related sites.