# Is the ask.antimoon.com website part of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I am confused about the **[ask.antimoon.com](http://ask.antimoon.com/)** website! Its interface and functionality looks very similar to Stack Overflow, but it doesn't refer back to any Stack Exchange website!

I just want to know if there is any relation between Stack Overflow and ask.antimoon.com. If not, why can ask.antimoon.com use Stack Overflow's theme? I don't think they shouldn't be able to do that, because it confuses users like me.

Comment: How is this website IN ANY WAY similar to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Loic see my edit

Comment: That site has some great questions and especially - answers. My favourite: [How to learn Mancunian?](http://ask.antimoon.com/questions/5149/how-to-learn-mancunian)

Comment: @Pekka: Did you create an account, just so you could flag as "not an answer"?

Comment: @Cody I was very tempted!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a Stack Exchange website?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/is-this-a-stack-exchange-website)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek's comment suggesting https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/is-this-a-stack-exchange-website (deleted) is a great duplicate suggestion, but no longer available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What other sites are using the Stack Overflow engine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49023/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054/282094 - neither as good as the prior comment.

Answer (score 10):

It's a StackExchange 1.0 site...it's a relic, nothing to worry about.

**Edit:** To clarify. Before [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) you could rent hosted Q&A sites from StackExchange. This is one of them. If you look at the [source code of it](http://ask.antimoon.com/), you'll find this:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```